# How to use JFormattedTextField allowing only letters and numbers

Tags: java, swing, validation, jformattedtextfield

I have this code and cannot get `MaskFormatter` right
[maskformatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter)

```
MaskFormatter formatter = null;
  try {
    formatter = new MaskFormatter("HHHHHHH");
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

txtTroll = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

I need Any hex character (0-9, a-z or A-Z) and the "H" should
give me only (0-9, a-z or A-Z) but im getting it wrong.

When i type text only capital letters are typed and it's slow to
and when i click away from the `txtTroll` all letters vanish

Comment: I'm not sure I see why the regex tag was added to this question.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The JFormattedText field is supposed to wipe your text when you go out of the window if that text is invalid, which shouldn't be happening and isn't on my computer. The letters are supposed to go to upper case automatically, that is the behavior of the mask formatter with the 'H' character. Edit: maybe your text box is getting wiped because you aren't filling it with characters before leaving it?

Comment: You may wish to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem directly.

Comment: Im doing it all wrong, will read up more because i want user only to input (0-9, a-z or A-Z)

Comment: The JFormattedTextField was behaving so strange so i ended up doing like this: [filter](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/apply-special-filter-to-a-jtextfield.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

u can use another solution that i prefer

write ur Document class and rewrite it's `insertString` method using `regex expr`

example:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

/**
*
* @author cpp-qt
*/
public class HexDocument extends PlainDocument {

private String text = "";

@Override
public void insertString(int offset, String txt, AttributeSet a) {
    try {
        text = getText(0, getLength());
        if ((text + txt).matches("[0-9a-fA-F]{0,7}")) {
            super.insertString(offset, txt, a);
        }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HexDocument.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

    }
}
```

then

set it as ur textField's document like this `this.jTextField1.setDocument(new HexDocument());`

i think this is better than using jFormattedTextField

Comment: no, subclassing that's no longer (since ... ages) the recommneded way to restrict the input to a textComponent. Instead, use a DocumentFilter (as @Sanjay already suggested)

Comment: btw, an answer is not restricted to sms length - so please write out the u* :-)

Comment: @kleopatra thanx, note : SMS length again :) i will see Document Filter

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems in your assumption, make sure what you need, if you need letters and numbers, HEX is **not** what you need,

> "H" should give me only (0-9, a-z or A-Z) but im getting it wrong.

This is wrong assumption, "H" should give you Any hex character **(0-9, a-f or A-F)**.

See the javadoc : [MaskFormatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html)

Also I'd suggest you to have a look at : [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Answer (score 0):

HHHH will make the output hexadecimal. Use AAAAAAA