# JFormattedTextField - How to allow only chars?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

I've got an ArrayList of Characters and I've also got a JTextField which returns a String. I was wondering how do I only permit chars to be entered? Or perhaps how could I only allow the first letter of the string to get passed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JFormattedTextField allowing only letters and numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203378/how-to-use-jformattedtextfield-allowing-only-letters-and-numbers)

Comment: _"how could I only allow the first letter of the string to get passed?"_ - Have you heard of `charAt`?

Answer (score 2):

So you only want to allow **certain** chars to be entered, chars that are held by an ArrayList? If so, I'd use a JTextField and then add a DocumentFilter to its Document.

---

**Edit**
Based on your comment:

> I want the input to be of type Character. By default I can type in 'a' into my JTextField and it will come out as type String whereas I want it to be of type Character. So If I have a method that passes in a char, and I try and pass in a String it doesn't work and I need it to be a char instead.

You've got an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here meaning your barking up the wrong tree and looking for the wrong solution, an impossible and illogical one. A JTextField will always hold Strings. Just get the char array from the String, `charArray()` and then use it.

Comment: I want any chars to be entered as a char type rather than a string

Comment: @LukaszMedza: sorry but your comment doesn't make sense to me. Strings are made of chars. Please clarify just what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want the input to be of type Character. By default I can type in 'a' into my JTextField and it will come out as type String whereas I want it to be of type Character. So If I have a method that passes in a char, and I try and pass in a String it doesn't work and I need it to be a char instead. I hope that this makes more sense.

Comment: @LukaszMedza: Please see edit to answer. You're looking for a non-existent solution to a non-existent problem.